Forbidden Exception in thread "main" io.kubernetes
I am using Kubernetes java client for creating a basic pod in my Kubernetes Cluster using following code:
import io.kubernetes.client.openapi.ApiClient;
import io.kubernetes.client.openapi.ApiException;
import io.kubernetes.client.openapi.Configuration;
import io.kubernetes.client.openapi.apis.CoreV1Api;
import io.kubernetes.client.openapi.models.*;
import io.kubernetes.client.util.Config;

public class CreatePodExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ApiException, Exception {
        // Load Kubernetes configuration from default location
        ApiClient client = Config.fromCluster();
        //Configuration.setDefaultApiClient(client);

        // Create CoreV1Api instance
        CoreV1Api api = new CoreV1Api(client);

        // Define metadata for the pod
        V1ObjectMeta metadata = new V1ObjectMeta();
        metadata.name("private-hello-container-test");

        // Define container spec for the pod
        V1Container container = new V1ContainerBuilder()
                .withName("private-hello-container-test")
                .withImage("test.azurecr.io/test/app:dev")
                .withImagePullPolicy("IfNotPresent")
                .withCommand("/bin/sh", "-c", "echo hello world!!")
                .build();

        // Define pod spec
        V1Pod pod = new V1PodBuilder()
                .withMetadata(metadata)
                .withNewSpec()
                .addToContainers(container)
                .endSpec()
                .build();

        // Create the pod
        V1Pod createdPod = api.createNamespacedPod("default", pod, null, null, null);
        System.out.println("Pod created: " + createdPod.getMetadata().getName());
    }
}

but getting following error:
Exception in thread "main" io.kubernetes.client.openapi.ApiException: Forbidden
        at io.kubernetes.client.openapi.ApiClient.handleResponse(ApiClient.java:993)
        at io.kubernetes.client.openapi.ApiClient.execute(ApiClient.java:905)
        at io.kubernetes.client.openapi.apis.CoreV1Api.createNamespacedPodWithHttpInfo(CoreV1Api.java:9907)
        at io.kubernetes.client.openapi.apis.CoreV1Api.createNamespacedPod(CoreV1Api.java:9873)
        at CreatePodExample.main(CreatePodExample.java:39)

I've tried few things here & there but no luck. how can I fix?

After checking the code which you have provided, we can understand that you are trying to create a pod using these Kubernetes client libraries. However, as mentioned here, for performing any sort of operation on a Kubernetes cluster you need to possess adequate privileges or permissions.

Also try to mention the steps which you have performed instead of just pasting the plain code and error message it will help fellow community members to understand your problem in much better way

I am able to resolve the issue. The issue was with Service Account permissions. Following are the resolved permissions.
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: Role
metadata:
  namespace: default
  name: job-creator
rules:
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["jobs", "pods"]
  verbs: ["create", "get", "list", "watch"]
- apiGroups: ["batch"]
  resources: ["jobs", "pods"]
  verbs: ["create", "get", "list", "watch"]

